# Some YouTube iframe embeds not working in HTML5 mode

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

A YouTube iframe can play a video using an HTML5 player instead of Flash, by adding "html5=1" as a URL parameter. However, this only works sometimes. For example the emebeds below are identical, except for the YouTube id in the iframe URL. The first iframe plays fine if there is no Flash player installed but the second requires flash. I've tried this in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="720" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/O_ceIIJeVNQ?html5=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;controls=0&amp;title&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=O_ceIIJeVNQ&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080"></iframe>

<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="720" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YmehSeNXXt4?html5=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;controls=0&amp;title&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=YmehSeNXXt4&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/2SAas

Any idea how I can get embeds to play in HTML5 consistently?

Answer (score 1):

@Jude Osborn

> "Apparently HTML5 video will not play for videos with ads, captions, or annotations"

That is impossible,  the biggest part of youtube videos will have ads captions or notations
if it was true Youtube would be dead soon.

The fact that one video will play and the other not
is probably caused by if a version exists that is available
in the right format...which might depend on how old it is.
They dont convert videos on the fly..but create various versions
and send the right one to the right browser or device.

It should be that the new(er)  embed code as shown below videos @Youtube
takes care of sending the right video to you.

By the way NONE of the PLAYLISTS will play anymore on iOS (iPad/iPhone)
i noticed that today, no replies are given in any yt-forum
Single videos play fine.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine found the answer in the original HTML5 video post announcement here:

http://youtube-global.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/introducing-youtube-html5-supported.html

Apparently HTML5 video will not play for videos with ads, captions, or annotations.